# How to connect to hue with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, philips-hue

I'm trying philips hue with Swift.
I want to turn on the light using HTTP request.
I'm using Net for HTTPRequest https://github.com/nghialv/Net

```
let net = Net()
let params = ["on":true]

let puturl = "http://[IP Address]/api/[username]/lights/1/state"
net.PUT(absoluteUrl: puturl, params: params, successHandler: { (responseData) -> () in
    println("success")
    }) { (err) -> () in
        println("err")
}
```

Xcode print "success" but the light can't turn on.
Please let me know why the reason.

Answer (score 1):

You need to authenticate ("push link") with the bridge first. You probably did not do that, which is why the lights won't respond.

Also I suggest that you first start with the official [Philips Hue SDK](https://github.com/PhilipsHue). It clearly has its issues, but it fundamentally works and is a good start before you re-implement all the requests on your own (which is quite a lot if you want to use all the Hue features).

Since Swift and Objective-C are bridge, the fact that the Hue SDK is written in Objective-C is not an issue. You only need to create a bridging header (AppName-Bridging-Header.h) with the line

```
#import <HueSDK_iOS/HueSDK.h>
```

and then you can use the Hue SDK from your Swift files.

Apple has a [great book on how to use Objective-C code from Swift files](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/using-swift-cocoa-objective/id888894773?mt=11).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that header.  I'll try again.

Answer (score 0):

With the Hue SDK comes a demo project. Have you tried that? It's not written in Swift (but Obj-C), however that shouldn't make a big difference. It works fine for me.

Also, did you authenticate your app with the bridge?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with that. I only tried the demo as OSX app.

Comment: Do you have any sample code for Philips Hue swift Integration